# Is it bad practice to connect a heatsink to my PCB's ground plane?

Tags: grounding, heat, heatsink, ground-plane, power-dissipation

So, basically, I have this LED project which is going to dissipate lots of heat (I am assuming close to 50W) inside a case. The LEDs themselves are on a separate aluminum board which will be attached to a heat pipe CPU cooler with a fan. The control circuitry for which I am designing a PCB will also get kind of hot based on formulas from the datasheet for the buck drivers (though theoretically still well below the ratings they give and assuming the low end of efficiency from component tolerances) and I'm wanting to help move that heat onto the cooler rather than sitting inside a closed case. I had the thought of connecting the cooler's heatpipes to the ground plane of the PCB with some exposed copper and using kapton tape to protect any vias that could short through the heatpipes if the solder mask were to be compromised.

Is this a bad idea? Is this something that people do often? To me it seems like it may reduce any noise because it would effectively make the ground plane bigger. I don't really see what would be problematic about it since any non-ground paths would be isolated from the heatpipes. The cooler itself will also be covered by a 3D-printed cage.

Comment: Grounding issues aside, adding a heat source in the middle of the heatpipe will compromise heat transfer at the cold end by evaporating some of the working fluid before it reaches it.  Conversely, if your LEDs are operating at a higher temperature than your board, some heat may transfer *into* your ground plane.

Comment: Which parts are you expecting to get hot? The buck converter itself shouldn't get particularly warm.

Comment: @td127 at 70W (assuming 50W LED heat 30% efficient LEDs), 90% efficiency means the part is burning 7W, so it could get preeeetty hot, even with the pcb full ground plane

Comment: Most of the heat in a switching power supply will be in the inductors, not the controller IC itself. As it's unlikely either side of the inductors are connected to ground, the plane won't help cool them.

Comment: I'm just going to change the way I put everything together so that the control board is away from the heat sink. It seems like it is more likely to cause problems and the converters should not really get too hot to cause problems anyways. It was really just a "just to be safe" thing but it seems it creates more non-safe issues.